# How to re-render an image sequence with different image texture for 1 object?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I did a Image sequence render of about 1500 frames only to notice that a small object in scene had a different texture file linked to it.. instead of re rendering the whole 1500 frames.. is it possible to use compositor to mask the rest of objects and only render small object that i need correction for and then combine teh original sequence with this new one?

Im new to compositing would appreciate if anyone can point me at an keywords i can use to google about this or solution.

Comment: Just put that single object in a different scene layer, then setup a render layer to include only that object and exclude all others.

Comment: Thanks i was new to composting spent some time learning and i was able to get this by rendering the object with transparent background and excluding rest of objects camera ray visibility but still keeping shadows on. then i composted the this onto my old renders.